# Selenium webdriver 2, can't get IE8 to open

Tags: internet-explorer-8, selenium

I cannot get selenium to work with IE8. I am on a mac osx 10.5.8 with paralells virtual environment running Windows xp.

I have set up selenium and Ruby and my ruby scripts work fine with firefox in Windows but I can't get IE to work. I have downloaded selenium-server-standalone-2.8.0.jar and put it in my CLASSPATH but I think I have done it incorrectly.

This is the beginning of the error I get:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:43:in 'for': unknown driver: :internetexplorer (ArgumentError)
```

So my guess is that my Ruby script is bad and
 `"driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :internetexplorer"` is incorrect? Or I have set the CLASSPATH for selenium-server-standalone-2.8.0.jar incorrectly so that InternetExplorerDriver cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

I've found my mistake: To open internet explorer the driver should be either `:ie` or `:internet_explorer`.